# Why does my SQL trigger statement not appear in DBMS_OUTPUT?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm trying to get my head around triggers, but I'm getting errors

> Error(2,4): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>
> Error(2,8): PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

when creating the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TableTrigger
AFTER UPDATE ON TestTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  set serveroutput on format wrapped;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('TABLE UPDATED!');
END;
```

Which works on the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
(
test1 INT,
test2 INT,
test3 INT,
PRIMARY KEY (test1)
);
```

I'm not sure what to do, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: set serveroutput on format wrapped; is an SQL*Plus command and has nothing to do in a trigger. Delete it.

Comment: @Mottor Thanks, I got rid of it. The errors are now gone, but on updating the table the message 'TABLE UPDATED!' still doesn't show up. I've enabled DBMS_OUTPUT for the connection.

Comment: Are you using SQL*Plus? If you are write "set serveroutput on format wrapped;" in SQL*Plus before your update statement. I have tested it by me and is working.

Comment: How have you enabled it, and where are you looking for the output to appear?

Comment: @Mottor, this worked, thanks for your help. I'm pretty new to SQL and it's a little difficult for me to understand exactly what's going on.

Comment: Only to mention "SQL trigger compilation errors" is not very good title for a question. Read "How do I ask a good question" http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the title to something I think is more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

Using DBMS_OUTPUT in triggers is not best practice.  If you want to see that something was done create a logging table or an audit history table or set auditing of update on for that table.

DBMS_OUTPUT is useful when you are running a PL/SQL procedure or package from SQLPlus or other IDE.

Different versions of SQL may or may not show you the output of the buffer from  a trigger.